# What is the correct way to close a popover?

Tags: swift, macos, popover, dismiss, nspopover

In my NSDocument subclass I instantiate an NSPopover, with `.semitransient` behaviour, and show it:

```
popover.show(relativeTo: rect, of: sender, preferredEdge: .maxX)
```

`popover` is declared locally. A button method in the popover controller calls:

```
view.window?.close()
```

The popover closes, but I have become aware that it remains in memory, `deinit()` is never called and the `NSApp.windows` count increases, whereas if I dismiss it by pressing escape or clicking outside it, `deinit` *is* called and the windows count doesn't increase.

If I set the window's `.isReleasedWhenClosed` to `true`, the windows count doesn't increase, but deinit is still not called.

(Swift 3, Xcode 8)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call [performClose](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nspopover/1534290-performclose) (or [close](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nspopover/1526823-close)) on the popover, not the window.

Comment: We're in a subclass of NSViewController which does not have this method. Nor does its view. The window is an NSPopoverWindow for which I can't find documentation.

Comment: Somewhere you declared that `popover` variable that you call `showRelativeTo:of:preferredEdge:` on. That's the object you need to call `performClose` on. If you have to close it from code within the NSViewController that is embedded in the popover, you have to figure out a way to access that object. Maybe create a PopoverViewController as a base class that has a popover property that you set before showing it. Or use a delegate pattern. Or use notifications (prefer other solutions though as this will result in spaghetti code very quickly).

Comment: I'd just tried that first idea, adding a reference to the popover and initialising before calling show(...). Then in the ' finished' method calling `popover.close()`. It closes OK but never deinits.

Comment: @AlexT How did you declare `popover`? It won't deinit if you're holding a strong reference to it.

Comment: It's declared locally.  I added a Cancel button without any code attached. The popover disappears, but `deinit` is not called, and bizarrely, the window is no longer in the `NSApp.windows` array, so it's hanging there in memory unreferenced.

Comment: There seemed to be some inconsistency according to whether I closed the popover with the escape key, or calling `view.window!.close()` . So I fabricated a escape keydown event and posted that instead. Not much difference. Sometime `deinit` fires after a few seconds after closing the popover; is that something like garbage collection at work?  For those interested (because it's hard to discover) the escape key is "\u{1B} and its key code is 53.

Comment: I've just found that there is a NSPopoverDelegate protocol, which your ViewController can adopt so as to receive notifications such as willShow, didClose etc. Assign it before calling `popover.show()`.  Not much use with this problem however.

Comment: One more comment! My popovers are attached to documents in a document-based app. Sometimes they can be brought up a dozen or more times. When I close the document, the deinit's all fire together. It appears they are owned in some way by the document, although I don't keep references to them after showing them.

Comment: @AlexT If you post a simple project demonstrating the issue, I can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks -DrummerB for your interest. It has taken me some time to get around to making a simple test application I might send you, and of course it wasn't a document-based one as mine was, and that seemed to be clouding the issue. My way of opening the popover was based on an example I'd recently read, but can't now find or I'd warn people. It went like this:

```
let popover = NSPopover
let controller = MyPopover(...)! // my convenience init for NSViewController descendant
popover.controller = controller
popover.behaviour = .semitransient // and setting other properties
popover.show(relativeTo: rect, of: sender, preferredEdge: .maxX)
```

Here's the improved way I've come across:

```
let controller = MyPopover(...)! // descendant of NSViewController
controller.presentViewController(controller, 
    asPopoverRelativeTo: rect, of: sender, preferredEdge: .maxX,
    behavior: .semitransient) // sender was a NSTable
```

In the view controller, the 'Done' button's action simply does:

```
dismissViewController(self)
```

which never worked before. And now I find the app's windows list doesn't grow, and the controller's `deinit` happens reliably.

Comment: Returning to this after a couple of weeks on other problems; this answer is not quite right. `deinit` is happening correctly, but the list of windows as reported by `NSApp.windows` keeps growing, but not if you used escape key to close the popover. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the following:

Define a protocol like this

```
protocol PopoverManager {
    func dismissPopover(_ sender: Any)
}
```

In your popoverViewController (in this example we are displaying a filter view controller as a popover) add a variable for the popoverManager like this

```
/// Filter shown as a NSPopover()
class FilterViewController: NSViewController {
    
    // Delegate
    var popoverManager: PopoverManager?
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        
    }
    
    // Bind this to the close button or action on your popover view controller
    @IBAction func closeAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.popoverManager?.dismissPopover(sender)
    }

   ...

}
```

Now in your viewController that you show the popover from add an extension like this

```
extension MainViewController: NSPopoverDelegate, PopoverManager {
    @IBAction func setFilter(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.showFilterPopover(sender)
    }
    
    func showFilterPopover(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Filter", bundle: nil)
        guard let controller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "FilterViewController") as? FilterViewController else {
            return
        }
        // Set the delegate to self so we can dismiss the popover from the popover view controller itself.
        controller.popoverManager = self
        
        self.popover = NSPopover()
        self.popover.delegate = self
        self.popover.contentViewController = controller
        self.popover.contentSize = controller.view.frame.size
        
        self.popover.behavior = .applicationDefined
        self.popover.animates = true
        self.popover.show(relativeTo: sender.bounds, of: sender as! NSView, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
        
    }
    
    func dismissPopover(_ sender: Any) {
        self.popover?.performClose(sender)
        // If you don't want to reuse it
        self.popover = nil
    }
}
```